# Elasticsearch の HTTP URL レポジトリは仕様として、ディレクトリの URL では何を返す必要がある？

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch の snapshot API を利用する際に、URL を指定することで、 Read-only のレポジトリとして取り扱うことができると、公式ドキュメントには記述があります。またその URL のプロトコルはいくつかの種類が利用可能で、その中に HTTP が含まれる、と記述されています。 (参照: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_read_only_url_repository )

また、前提として、 Elasticsearch snapshot の中身は、 lucene indices + メタデータのファイルたちから構成される、一種のディレクトリ構造であること理解しています。

そうであるとすると、 HTTP URL の read-only のレポジトリからデータを restore するためには、 ディレクトリに対応する URL に GET リクエストを送った場合には、そのディレクトリに含まれるファイル一覧が、特定の形式で帰ってこなければならない、と考えています。

Q1: 自分の理解は正しいでしょうか
Q2: そうであった場合、そのディレクトリに対して GET をした際のレスポンスは、どのような仕様に従うべきなのでしょうか。(どのような形式で返ってきていれば、それは URL レポジトリとして動作するのでしょうか)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urlタイプを試す前にリンク先のドキュメントにfsタイプを試してみてください。Elasticsearchのconfigで`path.repo`にサーチパスを指定してfsタイプでスナップショットを取ると、次のようなディレクトリ構成が出来上がります。下の例は`backups/my_backup`というディレクトリにsnapshot_1という名前のスナップショットを作成した例です。Elasticsearchはここからmetadata-スナップショット名のファイルを読み込んでいます。

Webサーバはmy_backupがルートになるように設定します。つまり`http://ホスト名/パス/`でアクセスした時にindex, indices, metadata-スナップショット名, snapshot-スナップショット名が見えていればOKです。Elasticsearchのconfigでは`repositories.url.allowed_urls: ["http://ホスト名/*"]`というように許可するURLをセットしておきます。

```
$ tree backups
backups
└── my_backup
    ├── index
    ├── indices
    │   └── myindex
    │       ├── 0
    │       │   ├── __0
    │       │   ├── __1
    │       │   ├── __2
    │       │   ├── __3
    │       │   ├── __4
    │       │   ├── __5
    │       │   ├── __6
    │       │   ├── __7
    │       │   ├── __8
    │       │   ├── __9
    │       │   ├── __a
    │       │   ├── __b
    │       │   ├── __c
    │       │   └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    │       ├── 1
    │       │   ├── __0
    │       │   ├── __1
    │       │   ├── __2
    │       │   ├── __3
    │       │   └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    │       ├── 2
    │       │   ├── __0
    │       │   ├── __1
    │       │   ├── __2
    │       │   ├── __3
    │       │   ├── __4
    │       │   ├── __5
    │       │   ├── __6
    │       │   ├── __7
    │       │   ├── __8
    │       │   ├── __9
    │       │   ├── __a
    │       │   ├── __b
    │       │   ├── __c
    │       │   ├── __d
    │       │   ├── __e
    │       │   ├── __f
    │       │   └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    │       ├── 3
    │       │   ├── __0
    │       │   ├── __1
    │       │   ├── __2
    │       │   ├── __3
    │       │   ├── __4
    │       │   ├── __5
    │       │   ├── __6
    │       │   ├── __7
    │       │   ├── __8
    │       │   ├── __9
    │       │   ├── __a
    │       │   ├── __b
    │       │   ├── __c
    │       │   └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    │       ├── 4
    │       │   ├── __0
    │       │   ├── __1
    │       │   ├── __2
    │       │   ├── __3
    │       │   ├── __4
    │       │   ├── __5
    │       │   ├── __6
    │       │   ├── __7
    │       │   ├── __8
    │       │   ├── __9
    │       │   ├── __a
    │       │   ├── __b
    │       │   ├── __c
    │       │   ├── __d
    │       │   ├── __e
    │       │   ├── __f
    │       │   ├── __g
    │       │   ├── __h
    │       │   ├── __i
    │       │   └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    │       └── snapshot-snapshot_1
    ├── metadata-snapshot_1
    └── snapshot-snapshot_1

8 directories, 74 files
```

Comment: index, snapshot-"snapshot名" のファイルたちが、そのディレクトリから取得するべきファイルたちへのリンクみたいに動作していることを確認しました。